# How do i excute onCreate method by creating an instance of a class in android

Tags: java, android

I have a MainActivity.java and SongLoad.java. The code of `MainActivity.java` is

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final int LOADREQUEST = 100;
private String callerClass = "DoubleMode";

ImageButton loadPlaylist1,loadPlaylist2;
ImageButton play1,play2;


SongLoad songloader = new SongLoad(callerClass);
MusicPlayerService musicplayer = new MusicPlayerService();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);
    loadPlaylist1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.load_button1);
    loadPlaylist2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.load_button2);
    play1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play1);
    play2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play2);
}

public void onLoad(View v) {
    int loadButtonPressed = v.getId();
    songloader.playListGenerator();
    musicplayer.songLoader(songloader.songIndex, loadButtonPressed);.. soon
```

SongLoad.java

```
public class SongLoad extends ListActivity{
public int songIndex = 0;
public String selectedSongPath;
public String callerClass;
final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
SongLoad(String callerClass) {
    this.callerClass = callerClass; 
}
SongLoad() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(callerClass == "DoubleMode")
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.playlist);
    }
}

public void playListGenerator() {

    mediaScanner(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++)  {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsListData.add(song);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
            R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.songTitle });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();
    // listening to single listitem click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
        // getting listitem index
        songIndex = position;
        selectedSongPath = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath");

    }
    });
}
```

Now my question is that when I create a object of SongLoad.java and call playListGenerator onCreate method is called. However I want it to execute. How do i do that?

Comment: Make your homework on `Activities` and how they are managed and started.

Comment: i readf your "question" 10 times and each time i understand it less. what do you want to do?

Comment: I agree with gunar. I don't think you understand the `Activity` class. Unless I don't understand your question, in which I agree with bofredo.

Answer (score 1):

> How do i excute onCreate method by creating an instance of a class in android

You don't.

> when I create a object of SongLoad.java

Delete this code. *Android* creates instances of activities; *you* do not. Also:

- Delete the `SongLoad` empty constructor
- Move the call to `playListGenerator()` from `MainActivity` to the `onCreate()` method of `SongLoad`
- Start up a `SongLoad` activity by calling `startActivity()` from the `onLoad()` method of `MainActivity`

Each activity works in relative isolation, just as one Web page of a Web app does not call JavaScript functions from some other Web page in the same Web app.

You will eventually need other changes, such as the proper use of background threads when doing I/O, but that will get you started.

You should also consider reading [the documentation on activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html).